# Can't set Vue data variable when using FileReader API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

In my application, I am trying to allow a user to upload a folder containing json files. I then want to be able to loop through those files and push each file to a data object (not here yet).

Currently, I can't even access the data object when the onload process is happening. I'm starting to wonder is this even possible in this type of manner or should i try something else?

I'm pretty new to Vue.

```
data() {
    orderedFiles: {}
    jsonData: "cat" // this is what I am trying to set to jsonResult
  }
```

Here are my methods:

```
        async jsonLoop(files){
          for(let file of files){
          let self = this
          let fr = new FileReader()
          fr.onload = (e) => {
            console.log("onload FIRED")
              let jsonResult = e.target.result
              document.getElementById('Json').textContent = jsonResult
              console.log(self.jsonData) // undefined
            }
            fr.readAsText(file)
          }
        },
        loadFiles (e) {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
          let files = Array.from(e.target.files)
          // sort files
          let orderFiles = this.orderFiles(files)
          this.jsonLoop(orderFiles)
          console.log(this.jsonData) // undefined
        }
      else {
      alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser. Please use a different browser');
        }
      }
```

Comment: I assume the issue is this `let orderFiles = this.orderFiles(files)`.  You're calling a variable like a method.

Comment: changing that doesn't effect anything unfortunately. Still cant set data property

Comment: You're never setting the value of `jsonData`.

Comment: i can't set the value of jsonData within onload because it logs as undefined. so if i try to set the value by doing this.jsonData = jsonResult, i get the response that it cant set jsonResult to undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `orderFiles` like it's a method and you need to parse the json with `JSON.parse()` to use it as an object.  In the code below I've put the unparsed string representation into `this.stringJSON` and i've put the parsed json into an array of objects in `this.parsedJsonArray`.

Try selecting two json files in the example.

```js
Vue.component('v-form', {
  template: '#myform',
  data() {
    return {
      fileinput: '',
      // jsonData: [],
      parsedJsonArray: [],
      stringJSON: '',
      orderFiles: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async jsonLoop(files) {
      const ourDiv = document.getElementById('Json');

      for (let file of files) {
        let self = this;
        let fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (e) => {
          console.log("onload FIRED")
          let jsonResult = e.target.result;

          // add json to div text
          // ourDiv.textContent += jsonResult;

          // add unparsed json string to our data
          self.stringJSON += jsonResult;

          // adding parsed json to our jsonData as an array of objects
          self.parsedJsonArray = [...self.parsedJsonArray, JSON.parse(jsonResult)];
          console.log(self.parsedJsonArray);
        }
        fr.readAsText(file);
      }
    },
    loadFiles(e) {
      if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        let files = Array.from(e.target.files)
        // sort files
        // let orderFiles = this.orderFiles(files)
        this.jsonLoop(files)
        console.log(this.jsonData) // undefined
      } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser. Please use a different browser');
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-form></v-form>
  <div id="Json"></div>
</div>

<template id="myform">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" @change="loadFiles" multiple><br/><br/>
        String JSON: <span>{{ stringJSON }}</span>
    </form>
</template>
```